# condition for initializing constants in interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an interface where I have defined constants used across application. I have a scenario where I need to initialize constants based on condition.

for eg , something like,

```
if(condition){
public static final test = "some value";
}
```

Is this possible.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the condition is false? Should it fail to compile?

Answer (score 1):

`Interface` contains no code.

Split your interface in many specific interfaces declaring and initializing their own constants.

This will follow the `Interface Segregation Principle` where a class doesn't have to be bored by some useless constants or methods.

Of course, Java let classes implement several interfaces at once. So if you have specific interfaces to mix up for one concrete class, this would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are to be implemented. They should not be used as carriers for constants. If you need such a thing you might consider a final class with a private constructor.

What you seem to want is a global variable or singleton, which are rather problematic designs, or something like a c preprocessor directive, dynamically evaluated at compile time.

So consider if it is really a constant you need - something which is defined at compile (or class loading) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set static final variable with condition in following way:

```
public class Test {

    public static final String test;
    static {
      String tmp = null;
        if (condition) {
            tmp = "ss";
        }
        test = tmp;
    }

}
```

You can do it in one line, also in interface with:

```
public static final String test = condition ? "value" : "other value";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface InitializeInInterface {

    public static final String test = Initializer.init();

    static class Initializer {
        public static String init() {
            String result = "default value";
            InputStream is = InitializeInInterface.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if ("bar".equals(properties.getProperty("foo"))) {
                result = "some value";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For this to work condition must be available at class loading time. I doubt that is the case.

Comment: @AmitD I added an example of how the condition could be loaded from a properties file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be another reason why Interface constants are bad. You can simply use `enums` Like below.

```
public enum Const {
    SAMPLE_1(10), SAMPLE_2(10, 20);

    private int value1, value2;
    private Const(int value1, int value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    private Const(int value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    //Value based on condition
    public int getValue(boolean condition) {
        return condition == true ? value2 : value1;
    }

    //value which is not based on conditions
    public int getValue() {
        return value1;
    }
}
```